# Codeigniter library file upload image file upload form does not work, url becomes duplicate

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, codeigniter-3, multipartform-data

I have a detailed codeigniter project code is below:

config.php file:

```
    <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/cicrud/codepolitan/Blog';
```

With the folder path controllers/codepolitan/Blog.php

```
 <?php

class Blog extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('codepolitan/Blog_model');
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
    }


    //Tambah
    public function add()
    {
        if ($this->input->post()) {
            $data['title'] = $this->input->post('judul');
            $data['content'] = $this->input->post('konten');
            $data['url'] = $this->input->post('link');

            $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size']             = 100;
            $config['max_width']            = 1024;
            $config['max_height']           = 768;

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('cover'))
            {
                echo $this->upload->display_errors();
            }
            else
            {
                print_r($this->upload->data());
                exit;
            }
            print_r($data);
            // var_dump($data);
            $this->Blog_model->adddata($data);
        }
    

        $this->load->view('/codepolitan/form_add');
        }
    
    }
```

Display files from the form.
With the folder path view/codepolitan/form_add.php

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo form_open_multipart();?>
    <div>
        <label>Judul</label>
        <input type="text" name="judul">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>URL</label>
        <input type="text" name="link">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Konten</label>
        <textarea name="konten" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Upload Cover</label>
        <?php echo form_upload('content', null, 'class="form-control"')?>;
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Simpan Artikel</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When running, choose a jpg or png file format and add the code in  url to be duplicated like this http://localhost/cicrud/codepolitan/Blog/codpolitan/Blog/add

If, add function code "`add()`" from controller "Blog.php" at  There is an error message "You did not select a file to upload." Whereas previously I had chosen a jpg or png file format.

Please provide an explanation why it is like that? How is the solution from the code above done?

Comment: change in index.php the path to system and application folder, see [Managing your Applications](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/managing_apps.html)

Comment: I have tried with the instructions "Relocating Your Application Directory" aimed at my codeigniter project path, namely the "cicrud" folder as my codeigniter project, provide more detailed instructions on Managing Your Application.

Just returned the following message: "Your application folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and fix this: index.php"